# Where does 'index' come from in QML ListView delegate?

Tags: listview, delegates, qml

I have just started learning QML and was trying to implement a simple table via a ListView (using [this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45168702/canonical-way-to-make-custom-tableview-from-listview-in-qt-quick) as a guide).

I wanted to make one of the columns editable so I used `TextField` in place of `Label` for that column. Where I came unstuck was finding how to write the updated value back into the model. I found the `setProperty` method on the model but it was not at all clear how to access the index of the delegate's 'current item' to provide as the first argument of the method call.

After trying and failing to use `currentIndex`, eventually I discovered that I could in fact use `index` but I don't understand how I should have known this and where it is documented. I ask this question because I suspect there are some basic concepts I am missing that should have made this obvious.

Comment: Same experience for me... It would really be much better if the Qt doc tells more details about it (rather than just "The model index is exposed as an accessible index property.")...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's mentioned in the documentation for [ListView::delegate](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#delegate-prop):

> The delegate provides a template defining each item instantiated by
>   the view. **The index is exposed as an accessible `index` property.**
>   Properties of the model are also available depending upon the type of
>   Data Model.

It's also mentioned on [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-modelview.html#view-delegates) page, though that's a little harder to find.

Comment: So it is - thanks! That is really embarrassing because I have looked at that doc multiple times and for some reason I had completely missed the mention of index.