# Qt 5.12 TableView Header Delegate

Tags: qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I've created this table view in Qt 5.12 with new `TableView` but I don't know how to create header for it, I read documentation there is no headerdelegate for it neither. Here some screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

so **how can i add headerDelegate for 5.12 TableView?**

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    ListModel{
        id:tableModel
        ListElement{
            identifier:1
            name:'value'
            title: 'test'
        }
        ListElement{
            identifier:2
            name:'value2'
            title: 'test2'
        }
    }

    width:1000; height: 500
    //

    TableView {
        id:trans
        LayoutMirroring.enabled: true
        LayoutMirroring.childrenInherit: true
        anchors.fill: parent
        columnSpacing: 1
        rowSpacing: 1
        clip: true
        model: tableModel

        delegate: Rectangle {

            Row{
                Rectangle{
                    implicitWidth: 100
                    implicitHeight: 50
                    Text{
                        text: identifier
                    }
                }
                Rectangle{
                    implicitWidth: 100
                    implicitHeight: 50
                    Text{
                        text:name
                    }
                }

                Rectangle{
                    implicitWidth: 100
                    implicitHeight: 50
                    Text{
                        text:title
                    }
                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

and TableViewColumn didn't work

```
Qc.TableViewColumn{
    title: 'id'
    role: 'identifier'
    width:100
}
```

i'm trying to set its header from c++ but sth is not ok with my code

```
class TableHelper : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:

    Q_INVOKABLE void setTableHeader(QObject & table){
        // get QTableView and Set QHeaderView 
        qDebug()<< "here";
    }
};
```

main :

```
TableHelper th;
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("tableHelper",&th);
```

qml :

```
Component.onCompleted: {
        tableHelper.setTableHeader(trans)
}
```

I have a break point in C++ code, but it never runs.

Comment: Richard Moe Gustavsen : "We’re also working on a TableHeader, TableModel, as well as a DelegateChooser" - http://blog.qt.io/blog/2018/08/29/tableview/

Comment: there is no delegate but some Overlays http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-tableview.html#overlays-and-underlays