# Tableview columns autofit

Tags: python, pyqt5, qml

I have an application that uses PyQt5, it has a tableview in QML that takes data from a pandas dataframe.

I need the columns width to fit the width of the content automatically every time I update the data with a new dataframe load. I haven't found anything new on this subject on forums and the old answers are very confusing, I can't believe that in 2021 there is no simple solution for something so common in table treatments.

The QML code I have is as follows:

```
TableView {
  id: tableView
  antialiasing: true
  width: parent.width
  height: parent.height
  columnWidthProvider: function (column) { return 200; }
  rowHeightProvider: function (column) { return 60; }
  leftMargin: rowsHeader.implicitWidth
  topMargin: columnsHeader.implicitHeight
  rightMargin: columnsHeader.implicitHeight
  Layout.fillHeight: true
  model: table_model
  delegate: Rectangle {
    color: "transparent"
    Text {
      text: display
      anchors.fill: parent
      anchors.margins: 10
      horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
      color: {
        if (temaescolhido.currentText == 'Claro') return 'Black'
          return 'White'
      }
      font.pixelSize: 15
      verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
    }
  }
  Rectangle { // mask the headers
    z: 3
    color: "transparent"
    y: tableView.contentY
    x: tableView.contentX
    width: tableView.leftMargin
    height: tableView.topMargin
  }
  Row {
    id: columnsHeader
    y: tableView.contentY
    z: 2
    Repeater {
      model: tableView.columns > 0 ? tableView.columns : 1
      Label {
        width: tableView.columnWidthProvider(modelData)
        height: 35
        text: table_model.headData(modelData, Qt.Horizontal)
        color: 'green'
        font.bold: true
        font.pixelSize: 15
        padding: 10
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        background: Rectangle { color: "#adadad" }
      }
    }
  }
  Column {
    id: rowsHeader
    x: tableView.contentX
    z: 2
    Repeater {
      model: tableView.rows > 0 ? tableView.rows : 1
      Label {
        width: 35
        height: tableView.rowHeightProvider(modelData)
        text: table_model.headData(modelData, Qt.Vertical)
        color: 'green'
        font.bold: true
        font.pixelSize: 15
        padding: 10
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        background: Rectangle { color: "#adadad" }
      }
    }
  }

  ScrollIndicator.horizontal: ScrollIndicator { }
  ScrollIndicator.vertical: ScrollIndicator { }
}
```

Comment: old answers are likely confusing because the TableView was only offically added in 2.12, before that we used to make most tables using ListView. I will have a go at an answer, if I have time. This feature has changed between versions 5.12 to 5.15, so in order to provide something useful, which version of Qt (or PyQt5) are you targetting?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I'm using qt 5.15.4 with Qtquick. But I am considering using qtwidgets to be able to do all the code in python (without qml), as I have more knowledge in this language. Do you think I would lose too much in creation possibilities by switching from qtquick to qtwidgets?

Comment: I don't think there is a simple answer to Widgets vs Quick. Quick has animations that use OpenGL to make use of 3D GPU, but I have read that Widgets has better integration with matplotlib, so it depends what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea with the new TableView is to set the implicitWidth and implicitHeight of the delegates, and then the TableView should size the rows and columns automatically.

Here is a trivial example:

[image]

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import Qt.labs.qmlmodels 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 500
    height: 500

    Row {
        id: buttons
        Button {
            text: "Press To Add Data"
            onClicked: {
                var index = myTableModel.rowCount + 1
                myTableModel.insertRow(0, {
                    "col 0": (1000000+index).toString(),
                    "col 1": index.toString().repeat(index)
                })
            }
        }

        Item {
            // button spacer
            width: 5
            height: 5
        }

        Button {
            text: "Press To Clear Data"
            onClicked: {
                myTableModel.removeRow(0)
            }
        }
    }

    TableView {
        id: tableView

        y: buttons.height
        height: parent.height - buttons.height
        width: parent.width

        columnSpacing: 0
        rowSpacing: 0
        clip: true

        model: TableModel {
            id: myTableModel
            TableModelColumn { display: "col 0" }
            TableModelColumn { display: "col 1" }

            rows: [
                {
                    "col 0": "0",
                    "col 1": "1"
                },
                {
                    "col 0": "2",
                    "col 1": "3"
                },
                {
                    "col 0": "4",
                    "col 1": "5"
                }
            ]
        }

        delegate: Rectangle {
            implicitWidth: childrenRect.width
            implicitHeight: childrenRect.height
            border.width: 1

            Text {
                padding: 5
                text: display
            }
        }
    }
}
```